# Postgresql and ssl start up error

Tags: postgresql

I am new to freenode and postgresql. I am trying to migrate from mysql to postgresql. Currently trying to set up server for ssl. Have created my server certs and configured the .conf files for ssl according to the manual as far as I can see. Trying to restart postgre sql service fails. Windows event log gives me an event ID of 0 and says

> pg_ctrl could not start server examine the log output.

I can't find any log detailing the failure to start in the postgresql folders.

I have tried to register the pgevent.dll as advised by the postgresql manual (18.11 of most recent version), but I get an error message

> The module "C:postgreSQL\pg10\lib\postgresql\pgevent.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found

I believe that means it is either not a registrable dll or it's corrupt.
Can anyone please advise how I can track on Windows the error that is causing Postgre to fail to start?

Comment: Examine the parameters `log_destination`, `logging_collector`, `log_directory` and `log_filename` in `postgresql.conf` to find your database log.

Comment: `log_destination` is commented out. As for the other settings, `logging_collector` is on. `log_directory` and `log_filename` are pointing to the postgreSQl data/logs folder and it is producing the standard daily log files, however, these are not showing the start up errors. I have been through the manual to see which of the various logging parameters may be of assistance, but couldn't find any that might be of assistance. I tried setting log_min_messages to "debug5" the highest, but that doesn't assist.

Comment: Cool. Try starting the server using the `postgres` executable and see what you get: `C:\path\to\postgres.exe -D C:\path\to\data_directory`

Comment: Just the job. Thanks ever so much. Problem fixed. My ssl certs had been placed in the root "data" folder. They needed to be in "data/pg10".